# QGIS-streets network: How to get the points equistant at a certain distance from one point given?

Tags: qgis, network

Into a network of streets (let’s suppose polilines or polygons): How to get  the points equistant at a certain distance from one point given?

I know how to do this with ArcGIS with Network Analyst  but I can’t use it now and I wonder if somebody can help me with QGIS.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq